# How to preview all file types with a webbrowser control within Microsoft Access 2010?

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, document

I am currently using a webbrowser control to preview documents within an access form which works great for text files, however all other file types will attempt to open in their respective programs.  I have a text box that queries a database for file locations and I point the webbrowser control at the text box to open the file location.  I don't have anything else set up at this time.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the deal with sql-server? please use tags properly. sql-server means Microsoft SQL Server. Thank you.

Comment: The access form is using a SQL Server database. I tagged it this way in case you had suggestions to make a form using SQL Server instead of access.